# Using a real certificate with rethinkdb cert chain bundle

Tags: nosql, ssl, certificate

I know the rethinkdb guide uses a self signed cert as an example. If I wanted to use a real certificate that I purchased, how can I add the bundle to the server conf? I add the certificate I purchased and key to the config:

```
driver-tls-key=/etc/ssl/star.cert.key
driver-tls-cert=/etc/ssl/star.cert.crt
```

Openssl s_client gives me the following

```
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

With this as the certificate chain:

```
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN = *.s0nr.co
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN = *.s0nr.co
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.s0nr.co
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
```

---

How can I use this cert properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. There was **--driver-tls-ca** option that I was missing. I found it in the rethinkdb manual (man rethinkdb).

```
TLS options:

  --http-tls-key key_filename                 private key to use for web
                                              administration console TLS
  --http-tls-cert cert_filename               certificate to use for web
                                              administration console TLS
  --driver-tls-key key_filename               private key to use for client driver
                                              connection TLS
  --driver-tls-cert cert_filename             certificate to use for client driver
                                              connection TLS
  --driver-tls-ca ca_filename                 CA certificate bundle used to verify
                                              client certificates; TLS client
                                              authentication disabled if omitted
  --cluster-tls-key key_filename              private key to use for intra-cluster
                                              connection TLS
  --cluster-tls-cert cert_filename            certificate to use for intra-cluster
                                              connection TLS
  --cluster-tls-ca ca_filename                CA certificate bundle used to verify
                                              cluster peer certificates
```

I set it in my rethinkdb instance conf file:

```
# TLS stuff
driver-tls-key=/etc/ssl/star.cert.key
driver-tls-cert=/etc/ssl/star.cert.crt
driver-tls-ca=/etc/ssl/star.cert.ca-bundle
```

And everything works as expected. openssl s_client returns the proper 0 (ok) code.

**Edit note:**
Although with the rethinkdb dump utility it looks like there is no ca option so I can't use a real cert anyway.